# How can I get the precision of a decimal in js?

Tags: javascript

This is probably a super easy thing to solve, but I just can't think of an elegant solution right now.

Given the following numbers, how do I find the precision (.0001) of each number.

```
126.01
1.3450
```

Update:
The number of digits after the decimal.

The output from the top two numbers would be.

```
.01
.0001
```

Comment: Precision is either the total number of digits in a number or the number of digits after decimal. Which one you're interested in?

Comment: FYI JavaScript fails at math. If you add .1 + .2 you get 0.30000000000000004. You need to convert decimals to integers before math to get a reliable answer. e.g. (1+2)/10

Comment: `1.3450`... that trailing 0 doesn't have any significance. It's stored internally exactly the same with or without it, so it's impossible to determine how "precise" that number is.

Comment: @sissonb: All languages fail at math... in fact, computers fail at math, because they have finite precision. (Unless of course you use a library that doesn't store the numbers as floats)

Answer (score 4):

You can't. All `Number`s have the standard JavaScript precision.

If you had `"126.01"` and `"1.3450"` (i.e. `String`s), then you could do something like:

```
console.log("The precision of " + str_number + " is " + str_number.split('.')[1].length + " decimal places");
```

Or use `0` if you want significant figures instead.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try building a simple function like:

```
function acc(num) {
  var splt = num.toString().replace(/\.|$/, '.').split('.');
  return splt[1].length
    ? 1 / Math.pow(10, splt[1].length)
    : Math.pow(10, /0*$/.exec(splt[0])[0].length);
}
```